# How to check if array of array contain atleast one element?

Tags: javascript

I am facing one problem in javascript filter.

Suppose this is an `array1`-

```
const array1 = [
    {
        title: 'Stock market news',
        symbols: ['SPY.US', 'GSPC.INDX', 'DJI.INDX', 'CL.COMM', 'IXIC.INDX', 'NQ.COMM', 'ES.COMM'],
    },
    {
        title: 'Neil Young urges Spotify',
        symbols: ['SPOT.US', '639.F', '639.XETRA']
    },
    {
        title: 'Neil Young urges Spotify',
        symbols: ['AAPl.US', '639.F', '639.XETRA']
    }
]
```

And this is an `array2`

```
const array2 = [
    {Code: "AAPL"},
    {Code: 'SPOT'}
]
```

I have to filer array1 and remove an object that not complete the condition. The condition is if the array1 symbols contain at least one element of array2 `Code`. I mean if the array2 `Code` is match arry1 symbols field at least one element.

In the above example, the result should be-

```
const array1 = [
    {
        title: 'Neil Young urges Spotify',
        symbols: ['SPOT.US', '639.F', '639.XETRA']
    },
    {
        title: 'Neil Young urges Spotify',
        symbols: ['AAPl.US', '639.F', '639.XETRA']
    }
]
```

Because this two object contain `AAPL` and `SPOT` in symbols field. I think I can clear all the things.

I am trying in this way-

```
const filterData = array1.filter(function (array1El) {
    return !array2.find(function (array2El) {
        return array1El.symbols.includes(`${array2El.Code}.US`);
    })
});
```

But it is not working. Please say me where I am wrong.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/TFM3vUVg

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

- Your `!array2.find` condition is backwards - you want to filter to include items for which `array2.find` *does* have a match, not items for which it doesn't.
- `'AAPl.US' !== 'AAPL.US'` - make them the same case before comparing.

It'd also be clearer to use `.some` instead of `.find`.

```js
const array1 = [
    {
        title: 'Stock market news',
        symbols: ['SPY.US', 'GSPC.INDX', 'DJI.INDX', 'CL.COMM', 'IXIC.INDX', 'NQ.COMM', 'ES.COMM'],
    },
    {
        title: 'Neil Young urges Spotify',
        symbols: ['SPOT.US', '639.F', '639.XETRA']
    },
    {
        title: 'Neil Young urges Spotify',
        symbols: ['AAPl.US', '639.F', '639.XETRA']
    }
]

const array2 = [
    {Code: "AAPL"},
    {Code: 'SPOT'}
]
const filterData = array1.filter(function (array1El) {
    return array2.some(function (array2El) {
        return array1El.symbols
            .map(s => s.toLowerCase())
            .includes(`${array2El.Code.toLowerCase()}.us`);
    })
});
console.log(filterData);
```

Or create a Set of matching symbols first, which I'd prefer for lower complexity.

```js
const array1 = [
    {
        title: 'Stock market news',
        symbols: ['SPY.US', 'GSPC.INDX', 'DJI.INDX', 'CL.COMM', 'IXIC.INDX', 'NQ.COMM', 'ES.COMM'],
    },
    {
        title: 'Neil Young urges Spotify',
        symbols: ['SPOT.US', '639.F', '639.XETRA']
    },
    {
        title: 'Neil Young urges Spotify',
        symbols: ['AAPl.US', '639.F', '639.XETRA']
    }
]

const array2 = [
    {Code: "AAPL"},
    {Code: 'SPOT'}
];

const codesToFind = new Set(array2.map(({ Code }) => Code.toLowerCase() + '.us'));
const filterData = array1.filter(
  ({ symbols }) => symbols.some(
    sym => codesToFind.has(sym.toLowerCase())
  )
);
console.log(filterData);
```

Comment: Won't hard-coding the `.us` suffix eliminate ever being able to query for the `.F` and `.EXTRA` symbols?

Comment: That appears to be the same logic OP is trying to use with ``.includes(`${array2El.Code}.US`);``. Perhaps he's intentionally trying to only find `.US`.

Answer (score 0):

We could use a regex alternation approach here:

```js
const array1 = [
    {
        title: 'Stock market news',
        symbols: ['SPY.US', 'GSPC.INDX', 'DJI.INDX', 'CL.COMM', 'IXIC.INDX', 'NQ.COMM', 'ES.COMM'],
    },
    {
        title: 'Neil Young urges Spotify',
        symbols: ['SPOT.US', '639.F', '639.XETRA']
    },
    {
        title: 'Neil Young urges Spotify',
        symbols: ['AAPL.US', '639.F', '639.XETRA']
    }
];

const array2 = [{Code: "AAPL"}, {Code: "SPOT"}];
var regex = new RegExp("\\b(?:" + array2.reduce((x, y) => x.Code + "|" + y.Code) + ")\\.US");
console.log(regex);  // /\b(?:AAPL|SPOT)\.US/
var output = array1.filter(x => x.symbols.some(e => regex.test(e)));
console.log(output);
```

The strategy here is to form a regex alternation of stock symbols, one of which is required.  We then filter the original array, using `some()` and the regex to ensure that any match has at least one required stock symbol.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this search multiple times, it would be best to build a symbol index and query that.

For example...

```js
const array1 = [{"title":"Stock market news","symbols":["SPY.US","GSPC.INDX","DJI.INDX","CL.COMM","IXIC.INDX","NQ.COMM","ES.COMM"]},{"title":"Neil Young urges Spotify","symbols":["SPOT.US","639.F","639.XETRA"]},{"title":"Neil Young urges Spotify","symbols":["AAPl.US","639.F","639.XETRA"]}]

const array2 = [{Code: "AAPL"},{Code: 'SPOT'}]

// utility function to write into the index
const writeIndex = (map, key, entry) => {
  const normalisedKey = String.prototype.toUpperCase.call(key)
  if (!map.has(normalisedKey)) map.set(normalisedKey, new Set())
  map.get(normalisedKey).add(entry)
}

const symbolIndex = array1.reduce((map, entry) => {
  // convert all symbols to tokens
  // eg AAPL.US becomes ["AAPL.US", "AAPL", "US"]
  const keys = entry.symbols.flatMap(symbol => 
    [symbol, ...symbol.split(".")])
  
  // add the entry for each symbol token
  keys.forEach(key => writeIndex(map, key, entry))
  return map
}, new Map())

// pull unique items out of the index for the given codes
const queryIndex = codes => Array.from(new Set(codes.flatMap(code => 
  [...symbolIndex.get(code) ?? []]
)))

console.log(queryIndex(array2.map(({ Code }) => Code)))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

---

Alternatively, you can use a nested [*some*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) clause with a string [*includes*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) check to see if the symbol contains your code.

```js
const array1 = [{"title":"Stock market news","symbols":["SPY.US","GSPC.INDX","DJI.INDX","CL.COMM","IXIC.INDX","NQ.COMM","ES.COMM"]},{"title":"Neil Young urges Spotify","symbols":["SPOT.US","639.F","639.XETRA"]},{"title":"Neil Young urges Spotify","symbols":["AAPl.US","639.F","639.XETRA"]}]

const array2 = [
    {Code: "AAPL"},
    {Code: 'SPOT'}
]

const normalise = str => str.toUpperCase()

const normalisedCodes = array2.map(({ Code }) => normalise(Code))

const filtered = array1.filter(({ symbols }) =>
  normalisedCodes.some(code =>
    symbols.some(symbol => normalise(symbol).includes(code))
  )
)

console.log(filtered)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```